# How to save image using method PUT with API

Tags: php, api

i am getting issue in PUT method. But everything is fine when i'm doing method post
here is some code :

```
<?php

header("Content-type: multipart/form-data");
include_once '../Database/database.php';


$status = array();
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["ImageKTP"]["tmp_name"]))
{
    $tmp_file = $_FILES["ImageKTP"]["tmp_name"];
    $ImageKTP = $_FILES["ImageKTP"]["name"];
    $upload_dir = "./uploads/" .$ImageKTP;
    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $upload_dir)) {
        $status['kode']=1;
        $status['deskripsi']='upload success';
        $ImageKTP = $upload_dir;
    } else {
        $status['kode']=0;
        $status['deskripsi']='upload failed';
        $ImageKTP = null;
    }
}

echo json_encode($status);

?>
```

But when i'm doing method put using application/json, the result is failed
[image]

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");
include_once '../Database/database.php';
include_once '../Controller/users.php';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);


$email=$data['email'];
$idcardnumber=$data['idcardnumber'];
$placeofbirth=$data['placeofbirth'];
$dateofbirth=$data['dateofbirth'];
$Gender=$data['Gender'];
$Religion=$data['Religion'];
$ImageKTP=$data['ImageKTP'];
$ImageSelfie=$data['ImageSelfie'];
$ImageFamilyMemberCard=$data['ImageFamilyMemberCard'];

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();
$user = new Users($db);

$stmt = $user->UpdateProfile($email, $idcardnumber, $placeofbirth, $dateofbirth, $Gender, $Religion, $ImageKTP, $ImageSelfie, $ImageFamilyMemberCard);
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    // create array
    $profile_arr=array(
        "success" => 1,
        "message" => "Successfully Update Profile!"
    );
}
else{
    $profile_arr=array(
        "success" => 0,
        "message" => "Update Profile Failed!",
    );
}
print_r(json_encode($profile_arr));

?>
```

I still didnt find out how to solve this problem cause i want to update profile using method PUT include other value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $_FILES array only works with [POST requests](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files). If you want to use PUT there are some configurations to the web server that need to be made first, you can find a detailed guide [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php).

Comment: is this need configuration also on database?

Comment: No, once the file is handled by PHP you can send it to the database the usual way.